# Normalize street addresses in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I would like to detect "numbers" but not only in a string, and format the string depending country settings.

Some countries put the number at the beginning of the string, other put it at the end.

Examples with current strings for Italia:

```
Via Treviso Mare 2 => need to detect 2
8C via Sergio Leone => need to detect 8C
Strada Provinciale 22 C => need to detect 22 C
19-20 Frazione Santa Maria => need to detect 19-20
9 - 11 via Giare => need to detect 9 - 11
Via Cesare Taiti 18-B => need to detect 18-B
```

What I want to obtain (put all numbers/groups at end in Italy):

```
Via Treviso Mare 2
via Sergio Leone 8C
Strada Provinciale 22 C
Frazione Santa Maria 19-20 
via Giare 9 - 11 
Via Cesare Taiti 18-B
```

This is an example for Italia, for other countries, it's the contrary, so I will create 2 cases.

The problem is to create the regexp to match all these possibilities in my string:

```
2
8C
22 C
19-20
9 - 11
18-B
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: What did you try? The biggest problem is that addresses can be so wildly different that your regex cannot possibly parse all possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/4MRFkP/2)'s one regex, tailored for your examples :

```
/\b\d[\d\- ]*[A-Z]?\b/
```

It means :

- a digit
- followed by 0 or more digits, spaces or `-`
- followed by 0 or 1 letter.

It cannot possibly work for every italian address, though. The formats differ so wildly that no regex could understand them all.

Note that the found regex might have trailing spaces. You can call `strip` on the match.

Comment: I tested the regex at Rubular and it is working like a charm ! I will transform it if necessary for other countries. Thanks you Eric !